# (flask + socket.IO) Result of emit callback is the response of my REST endpoint

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Just to give a context here, I'm a node.JS developer, but I'm on a project that I need to work with Python using Flask framework.

The problem is, when a client request to an endpoint of my rest flask app, I need to emit an event using socket.IO, and get some data from the socket server, then this data is the response of the endpoint. But I didn't figured out how to send this, because flask needs a "return" statement saying what is the response, and my callback is in another context.

**Sample of what I'm trying to do:** (There's some comments explaining)

```
import socketio
import eventlet
from flask import Flask, request

sio = socketio.Server()
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/test/<param>')
def get(param):
    def ack(data):
        print (data) #Should be the response
    sio.emit('event', param, callback=ack) # Socket server call my ack function
    #Without a return statement, the endpoint return 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), app)
```

Maybe, the right question here is: **Is this possible?**

Comment: Why not just return an empty string along with a 200?

Comment: Because I need to return the parameter received on the callback executed on the socket.IO server (it's not the client)

Comment: This is not your main question, but consider that if you want to emit to a Socket.IO server (not to your clients) then you have to use a Socket.IO client here. A server cannot talk to another server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to give you one way to implement what you want specifically, but I believe you have an important design flaw in this, as I explain in a comment above. In the way you have this coded, your `socketio.Server()` object will broadcast to all your clients, so will not be able to get a callback. If you want to emit to one client (hopefully not the same one that sent the HTTP request), then you need to add a `room=client_sid` argument to the emit. Or, if you are contacting a Socket.IO server, then you need to use a Socket.IO client here, not a server.

In any case, to block your HTTP route until the callback function is invoked, you can use an `Event` object. Something like this:

```
from threading import Event
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/test/<param>')
def get(param):
    ev = threading.Event()
    result = None

    def ack(data):
        nonlocal result
        nonlocal ev

        result = {'data': data}
        ev.set()  # unblock HTTP route

    sio.emit('event', param, room=some_client_sid, callback=ack)
    ev.wait()  # blocks until ev.set() is called
    return jsonify(result)
```

Comment: ev.wait() is blocking my application, so the code on the callback function is not being executed, is there a easy way to change flask to work non-blocking?

Comment: Did you monkey patch the standard library for eventlet?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using FastAPI + socketIO (async version) and I was stuck at the exact same point. No eventlet so could not try out the monkey patching option.

After a lot of head bangings it turns out that, for some reason, adding `asyncio.sleep(.1)` just before `ev.wait()` made everything work smoothly. Without that, `emit`ted event actually never reach the other side (socketio client, in my scenario)